# How to include module of service class in spring log? SPRING + CXF

Tags: java, spring-boot, cxf

I have a multi-module Spring + CXF project running.

The different modules contain many different JAXRS and JAXWS CXF Servers and more, with very varying, but unique url prefixes.

I have my own "CommonsRequestLoggingFilter" implementation. Now I want to improve it. My goal is to include in the MDC/log message, in which module/package the serving service class is (in case of a request mapped to a cxf endpoint).

Changing to some CXF interceptor based request logging is not an option, I have to improve this spring based one, for other reasons.

I have tried to collect the CXF's registered destinations to check which one is fit by the request uri, but I could not find a way to map resource classes to them.

Eg.:
I have a cxf endpoint configured like this:

```
        JAXRSServerFactoryBean endpoint = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
        endpoint.setAddress(basePath + "/asdf/);
        endpoint.setServiceBeanObjects(myresources.toArray());
...
        return endpoint.create();
```

(myresources array can contain only resources from the same module/root package)

If a request is coming to /asdf/* I would like to see it in the SPRING logs, which module/package the service classes are (myresources).

Comment: there are no modules, only a classpath. At runtime those multi modules don't exist anymore.

Comment: Good point. It is okay to get the package for me though...